# Avoiding setter to change value of class's property

Tags: oop, encapsulation, setter, getter-setter

I have a class with one private field:

```
class Person {
  string name;
  public void setName(string name);
}
```

Then, using some object which is responsible for interacting with user (in this example by command line), I want to change the value of this field:

```
Person somePerson;
CommandLineView view;
somePerson.setName(view.askUserForName());
```

It works. But I don't like using `set` function as it exposes class members.
Therefore I started looking how to avoid it.

New implementation looks like this:

```
class Person
{
  string name;
  public void changeName(view) { name = view.askUserForName(); }
}
```

and:

```
Person somePerson;
CommandLineView view;
somePerson.changeName(view);
```

Now `Person` does not expose its member. Moreover this class is responsible for logic related to changing name (for example function `changeName` could also update database, notify interested parties etc.

The question is: Is such kind of refactoring a good practice? Or maybe implementation with `setter` was better, even if it break encapsulation?

Comment: don't know if this question fits in here - but IMO the way you use it now does couple `Person` way to tightly to `CommandLineView` - better to have an setter or just a `changeName` method (taking the new name) - it's ok to have the view depend on the model (obviously) but the other direction is a big *warning* sign!

Comment: Why don't you want to expose name?

Comment: @Carsten - so what do you think about inserting a new layer between `person` and `view`, for example some presenter?

Comment: @SimonWood - isn't exposing private fields considered as a code smell? In my opinion there is nearly no difference between `public` field and `private` one with setter and/or getter.

Comment: why another layer of indirection? I guess you would want to use the presenter in your model and in your view - so you would have the view depend on the model and the presenter, the presenter depend on the model and the view  ... nothing gained - sorry but I just don't see why you don't want the KISS setter ^^ - this OO is way to enterprisy for my taste

Comment: the difference with the setter is that you can change the backing field without exposing that change (as long as you can adapt the setter without changing it's signature) - for example if you have an cache with an (key,value)-pair list as backing field and later decide to move to a map you will not see it in your interface

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be no method to set the name at all, it should be a constructor parameter:

```
Person somePerson(view.askUserForName());
```

Problem with your approach is that you first create the object which is not fully initialized, so is dangerous to use: `Person somePerson`. What if you forget to `setName`? Will your code still work with this "empty" person?

And then you allow to directly modify the internal state with `setName` method, which is also not good.

Using the constructor parameter you avoid both of these problems.

As for the original question - I don't think there is big difference between the two methods.
The result is exactly the same - you call the method and the internal object state changed. You can name it `setName` or `changeName`, result is the same.

The second method with `changeName(view)` actually is worse because you also introduce the dependency of the `Person` on the `View` object.
Now, if you want to change the name, you always need to create the `View` object first.

Comment: Of course person without name can exist in the software! I can represent, for example, people I see through the window - I know much about their appearance, but I will know their name only after I open the window and ask for it ;) But it is not the point of the discussion.

Comment: I agree, maybe dependency on `View` is bad. Maybe it should depend on something like `NameChanger`. I have read an Yegor Bugayenko's article: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html and I'm following this sentence:
"An object can be teared apart by other objects, since they are able to inject any new data into it, through setters. The object simply can't encapsulate its own state safely enough, since anyone can alter it."
The keyword here is "safely" - I believe that permitting only specified objects to change state of `Person` helps in avoiding some bugs.

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski I think you are trying to trick yourself and find some fancy way to have a setter for a name, while what the article says is that you should avoid having setters at all. Here is a quote: `The dog is an immutable living organism, which doesn't allow anyone from the outside to change her weight, or size, or name, etc.`. Basically, if you have a getter and a setter, in the any form, it is the same as just declare the `name` filed to be `public`: `person->name = "New name"`. Does it look not good? But that's what it actually is when you have a setter.

Comment: "Basically, if you have a getter and a setter, in the any form, it is the same as just declare the name filed to be public" I agree!
But I don't think that in `changeName(view)` from my question there is a hidden `setter`. The value of `name` is being changed inside `Person` class. It is not changed from outside.

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski but then someone does `view = new CommandLineView("New Name"); person->changeName(view);`, if this is possible then you actually have a setter.

Comment: I don't understand: you mean that `CommandLineView`'s constructor takes `Person`'s name as parameter?

Comment: No, this is just an example, what I mean is that once you have a way to change the person's name, even through the external object, someone will abuse it as a setter by manually constructing the `CommandLineView` object and passing to the `changeName`. And if you have something like `NameChanger` object, it will be even easier to use it as a setter. I am trying to say that the basic choice here is simple - you whether have the setter in any form or don't have it (and pass the name into the constructor).